# Not able to access Kibana running in a Docker container on port 5601

Tags: elasticsearch, docker, dockerfile, kibana-4

I have built a docker image with the following Docker file.

```
# gunicorn-flask                                                                                                                                                                         

FROM devdb/kibana

MAINTAINER John Doe <user.name@gmail.com>

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y python python-pip python-virtualenv gunicorn

# Setup flask application
RUN mkdir -p /deploy/app

COPY gunicorn_config.py /deploy/gunicorn_config.py
COPY app /deploy/app

RUN pip install -r /deploy/app/requirements.txt

WORKDIR /deploy/app

EXPOSE 5000 5601 9200

# Start gunicorn
CMD ["/usr/bin/gunicorn", "--config", "/deploy/gunicorn_config.py", "listener:app"]
```

I am running the container from the image created from this Docker file as follows.

```
sudo docker run -p 5601:5601 -p 9200:9200 -p 5000:5000 -v /home/Workspace/xits/config/elasticsearch.yml:/opt/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml -v /home/Workspace/xits/config/kibana.yml:/opt/kibana/config/kibana.yml es-kibana-gunicorn:latest
```

The issue I am facing is that I cannot access Kibana port 5601 on my host machine. My browser page says `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

I am able to access port 5000 though.

I can't figure out why this is.Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parent Dockerfile [devdb/kibana](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/devdb/kibana/dockerfile/) is using a script to start kibana and elasticsearch when the docker container is started. See [`CMD ["/sbin/my_init"]`](https://github.com/abh1nav/docker-kibana/blob/master/Dockerfile#L18) and [the script](https://github.com/phusion/baseimage-docker/blob/master/image/bin/my_init) itself.

When in your own Dockerfile you use the [`CMD`](https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#cmd) instruction, you override the one from the parents Dockerfiles.
Since your `CMD` only starts gunicorn, elasticsearch and kibana won't ever be started. That's why there is no response on their respective network ports.

The Docker image you inherits from inherits itself from [phusion/baseimage](https://github.com/phusion/baseimage-docker) which has its own way of making multiple processes run in Docker containers. I recommend you follow the [instructions](https://github.com/phusion/baseimage-docker#adding-additional-daemons) on their README file to learn how to add your gunicorn to the list of services to start. Basically you would have to define a script named `run` and add it to your docker image within the `/etc/service/<service name>/` directory.

In your Dockerfile, add:

```
COPY run /etc/service/gunicorn/
```

and the `run` script should be something similar to:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /deploy/app
/usr/bin/gunicorn --config /deploy/gunicorn_config.py listener:app
```